# Dynamic cc:insertChildren render

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, composite-component

I got the problem when control to render cc:insertChildren dynamically.

```
<cc:implementation>
    My text 1
    <c:if test="#{testData}">
        <cc:insertChildren /> <!-- My content will be loaded here-->
    </c:if>
    My text 2
    <c:if test="#{!testData}">
        <cc:insertChildren /> <!-- or other will be loaded here-->
    </c:if>
</cc:implementation>
```

but the content rendered in both cc:insertChildren tags could not be rendered.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: So, `#{testData}` is not available during view build time? E.g. it represents `var="#{testData}"` of an iterating JSF component? Hard to answer without a MCVE.

Comment: No, It could not be rendered even I set  <c:if test="true"> and  <c:if test="false">

Comment: Oh, so the `xmlns:c` simply doesn't work at all? I.e. when you rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser, you still see all `<c:xxx>` tags in there?